# Maven archetype:generate doesn't list templates

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-archetype

I am learning Maven and trying to understand how it works, and I need little help.

When I type in cmd:`mvn archetype:generate`

I get this weird list, where I can't see number for JavaEE web application.

[image]

Anyway, I am following this tutorial, and he gets good template list.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpNnbBmh5J4&list=PL92E89440B7BFD0F6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of typing a number you can type any search string and it will narrow it down to just the archetypes containing that string. Try typing "javaee" (I get 19 results) or "jee" (15 results) at the prompt. After filtering, hitting just enter (without typing anything) will return you to the full list so you can try another filter.

Comment: I get also 19 results when a search "javaee". Anyway, I am not sure which of this 19 to choose, for example when I just want to develop web app with Servlets and JSP.

Comment: It seems like we have the same list... if you're just gonna use Servlets and JSP, and not bother with EJBs etc, then I'd go with `9: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee6 (-)`. Remember, this is not set in stone by any means! This is just a template that you will be able to make changes to and even rewrite later, if you need to. Don't sweat it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the full list of archetype available now.
The tutorial you are watching is from 2011, so more archetypes have been added since then.

what you can do to have the full list of archetype is redirecting the output to a file:

```
mvn archetype:generate > myfilte.txt
```

Currently the list of archetype containing word `jee` is :

```
259: remote -> net.thejeearchitectcookbook:jsf-jqmobile-archetype (JSF 2 and JQuery Mobile basic web archetype.)
520: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:appclient-jee5 (-)
525: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ear-jee5 (-)
530: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ejb-jee5 (-)
543: remote -> org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-jee5 (-)
586: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-basic-archetype (-)
587: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-minimal-archetype (-)
588: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-sandbox-archetype (-)
589: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-sandbox-demo-archetype (-)
590: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-servlet-basic-archetype (-)
591: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-servlet-demo-archetype (-)
592: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-servlet-minimal-archetype (-)
593: remote -> org.fluttercode.knappsack:jee6-servlet-sandbox-archetype (-)
630: remote -> org.imixs.application:imixs-workflow-jee-archetype (Imixs Workflow JEE Archetype provides a JEE Sample Application)
673: remote -> org.jboss.weld.archetypes:weld-jsf-jee (Weld archetype for creating a Java EE 6 application using JSF 2.0, CDI 1.0, EJB 3.1 and JPA 2.0 (persistence unit included))
674: remote -> org.jboss.weld.archetypes:weld-jsf-jee-minimal (Weld archetype for creating a minimal Java EE 6 application using JSF 2.0, CDI 1.0 and EJB 3.1 (persistence unit not included))
```

Comment: Which template I should choose for web application based on Servlets and JSP? On that tutorial he choose 259 for webapp-javaee1.4